Importing information of just one column from another table
I want to fill out a column named employee_id from another table by using select below is my query
INSERT INTO information (employee_id)
VALUES (SELECT employee_id FROM employee)

with the above query I am getting an error:
MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
near 'SELECT employee_id FROM employee)' at line 3**


Also is it mysql or sql-server ?

FYI - this - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert/ - is the MARIADB Manual for the INSERT statement. The 'near ...' refers to the where MariaDB failed to match what you inputted to the syntax it knows. What would make the reading of SQL error messages by users in trouble occur?

Are there other columns in the target table?  If so, don't you want a multiple-table UPDATE?

try like this:
INSERT INTO information (employee_id)
SELECT employee_id FROM employee;

